# In ObjC, how can I convert enum to id?

Tags: objective-c, syntax

Given method signatures like this:

```
+ (MY_ENUM_SET_A) stringToEnum:(NSString*)strVal;
+ (MY_ENUM_SET_B) stringToEnum:(NSString*)strVal;
```

I want to change them to:

```
+ (id) stringToEnum:(NSString*)strVal;
```

But in my implementation method before returning: Do I need to cast or do anything special to convert an enum to id?

Comment: This question makes no sense. If you have methods that return a string based on the value of an enum, then you already return `NSString *` or `id`. Then why would you need to cast **anything?** If you're trying to do `return (id)someEnumValue;`, then don't do that - read a C and Objective-C tutorial instead.

Comment: there is no direct cast or conversion between them. the `id` is representation of any random Objective-C class, the `enum` is typically represents `int` or `unsigned int` values.

Comment: And you're aware that `id` means *pointer to object* and an `enum` is basically a fixed-value integer and that they aren't the same thing.  Perhaps you haven't phrased your question correctly and this isn't what you want to do...

Comment: @trojanfoe - yup am aware. I really didn't want to use two different method names so I was wondering if there was any way to stick to one via an `id` return for enum ... didn't think it could be done ... but what do I know right? So I made sure to post and ask some experts. @H2CO3 - Did not expect the condescending tone though :(

Comment: I think you want to keep them separate because they are separate `enum`s so I would recommend doing what you are currently doing.

Comment: @trojanfoe - if you can move your comment into the answer area, i will mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to keep them separate because they are separate `enum`s so I would recommend doing what you are currently doing.